# Wagon or Vagon or Waggon - what is a correct word?

Tags: word-choice

Wagon or Vagon or Waggon - what is a correct word?

I need to name a piece of a train (carriage).

[Vagon](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vagon)
and
[Wagon](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wagon#English)
both have Wiki pages and there is no explanation about what is a correct way. Both seems to have the same roots and etymology.

Is it something to do with American/Britain rules?

Comment: Vagon has a Wiktionary page, but none of the definitions listed are in English. *Wagon* is the English word.

Comment: Wagon or Vagon - ask [Google](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vagon%2Cwagon%2Cwaggon&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=0&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvagon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwagon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwaggon%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I hate people who downvoted my question. I did not know the answer, now I know, but it costed me my reputation. Why?

Comment: Because if you had read the link in your question, you would have discovered that Vagon is not an English word.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Yes, it was my mistake. I did not know how "wiktionary" works. Thank you for explaining me that it has listed the languages where the word is used. I thought it was enough to look into the url and check that I'm reading an English version. You are right, no other person in the world ever would make such a silly mistake and this question have no community value. It should be downvoted until deleted.

Comment: Or you could edit it, and then it would be an acceptable question. Or delete it yourself.

Comment: All words are incorrect. Otherwise they'd have no interest.

Comment: DJ, I'd be happy to improve the question, but I don't know what would make it better. It perfectly expresses the confusion I had when I needed help. I edited it, I added "Waggon" in the mix.

Comment: You could remove the reference to "Vagon". That's the reason you are getting most downvotes.

Comment: Thank you DJ. It was my initial problem. I could not find a place where Vagon would be explicitly called "not an English word". On the contrary, Google was gladly giving me images and mentionings of this word as if it was English.

Comment: In AE, we call most of them *cars*: Dining car, passenger car, Pullman car.

Comment: I can recall reading "vagon" in what I'm guessing was archaic English (it's been a long time).  I'm thinking it was referring to some sort of train car.  A railroad nut might recognize the term.

Comment: @HotLicks - or just a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vagon is not an English word. It never has been except perhaps way back before English was a separate language.

On the link you provide, the word is shown to exist in several languages. It is also described as deriving  *from* English "wagon" but I can see nowhere that it says that the word *is* English. If that is implied by the page, then the page is incorrect and should be edited.

Wagon or Waggon are the English versions.

As @user 66974 says in a comment, the spelling with "gg" is rare these days https://grammarist.com/spelling/wagon-waggon/

Comment: ***Wagon vs. waggon*** : https://grammarist.com/spelling/wagon-waggon/

Comment: @user 66974 - Thanks. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: The link I provided is from Englis wiki, It says "en" at the URL. Why some one added a Kurdish clause there, I don't know.

Comment: I don't know but "vagon" is definitely not an English word. The Wiki is wrong.

Comment: I hate people who downvoted my question. I did not know the answer, now I know, but it costed me my reputation. Why?

Comment: I didn't downvote.  Some people like downvoting. Look at any YouTube video!  In this case I can guess it is because you didn't do any research by checking the Wiki entry against a range of well-known English dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Yes, it was my mistake. I did not know how "wiktionary" works. Thank you for explaining me that it has listed the languages where the word is used. I thought it was enough to look into the url and check that I'm reading an English version. You are right, no other person in the world ever would make such a silly mistake and this question have no community value. It should be downvoted until deleted.

Comment: There is downvoting and there is voting to close - They are different. I will vote to close as you request. I believe that you may also vote to close your own question although I have never tried it.

Comment: Thank you, Chasly. I'm new to this community. I'm learning the local rules hard way. I feel embarrassed now for my question, and I feel whipped for it, as I should be. I accept it as a cost of knowledge. Nothing is free in this word.

Comment: You are taking this too seriously.  Your question will disappear from view very soon and no-one will ever see it again. We all make mistakes - especially when learning a new language.

Comment: Thank you, Chasly. But let me correct you. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40299080/is-there-a-way-to-extend-a-trait-in-php) is my question from 5 years ago. There are people who still voting it up.

Comment: @Yevgeniy Afanasyev - Life is tough. A lot worse can happen! When I started here I ran into trouble a lot. I didn't care. I just gradually got better at avoiding the worst mistakes. Nowadays I don't mind how much people downvote or criticise me. I have have developed a thick skin - and a high rep!

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to passenger trains consisting of passenger  carriages one or more of which has an motor and at least two have control cabs so that the train can be driven in either direction the entire train is referred to as a Diesel Multiple Unit (DMU) if powered by diesel or an Electic Multiple Unit (EMU) if powered by electricity.

A unit which is part of a DMU or EMU and has a motor is known as a 'power car'. Sometimes a DMU or EMU will consist entirely of power cars.

A single car with an engine and control cabs at both ends is called a 'railcar' or, sometimes, a 'bubble' car.

It has been known for two railcars to be coupled together to make a two-car train. In some cases I believe that only one motor is used at any one time because there is no control connection possible from one to the other but both cars are still power cars because they both have motors.

Much of this information, together with much more can be found on [this website](https://www.railcar.co.uk/technology/the-basics/)  among others.

The term I think you are looking for is 'power car'. This is in contrast to a 'locomotive' or 'railway engine' which has no passenger seating and provides the power for a much longer train of unpowered passenger carriages or goods trucks (otherwise known as wagons).

Unpowered railway passenger vehicles are called carriages, coaches or cars. Railway goods vehicles are called 'wagons' (sometimes spelt waggons), trucks and, sometimes (particularly in the US), cars. Passenger cars are never called 'wagons' or 'trucks', goods cars are never called 'coaches' or 'carriages' and to my knowledge there are no goods wagons with motors. Also 'vagon' or vagòn does not exist in English. It is a Spanish word.

I hope this answers your question

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why have you spent so much time answering a question that you did not like?

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev I didn't say I didn't like your question and certainly didn't downvote it. I admit that I didn't upvote it either but that only means that I didn't find it particularly fascinating. There are very few questions here that have that effect on me. "Drive-by" downvotes where no comment is made annoy me because there is no possibility of arguing one's case with the downvoter.